# Autoscaling an svg on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-svg

I have this code:

```
function myClient() {
  if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
    return new arguments.callee(arguments);
  }
  var self = this;

  this.init = function() {
    self.viewResized();
    self.drawSvg();
  };

  this.viewResized = function () {
      var width = $('body').width(),
          windowHeight = $(window).height(),
          svgCanvasHeight = width * (369.0 / 567.0);
          $('#svg').css({
            'margin-top': 10
          });
    }

  this.drawSvg = function() {

    // ...
}

var myClient;

jQuery(function() {
  myClient = new myClient();
  $(window).resize(function() {
      console.log("window resized");
      myClient.viewResized();
    });
});
```

How do I get the svgCanvasHeight in drawSvg dynamically so that when the window is resized, so does the svg's viewBox and svg?

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: [Get the real size of a SVG/G element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847684/get-the-real-size-of-a-svg-g-element)

**With regards to viewBox:**

I have had a lot of problems with SVG and jQuery.

While html attributes are case-insensitive the svg ones (like viewBox) aren't. I'd try using the element.setAttribute(name, value) native JS function. This worked for me, and make sure you're using viewBox with the capital B.