# Get width/height of SVG element

Tags: javascript, svg

What is the proper way to get the dimensions of an `svg` element?

http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/Xkv3X/

Chrome 28:

```
style x
client 300x100
offset 300x100
```

IE 10:

```
stylex 
client300x100 
offsetundefinedxundefined
```

FireFox 23:

```
"style" "x"
"client" "0x0"
"offset" "undefinedxundefined"
```

There are width and height properties on `svg1`, but `.width.baseVal.value` is only set if I set the width and height attributes on the element.

---

The fiddle looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="green" />
    <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

**JS**

```
var svg1 = document.getElementById('svg1');

console.log(svg1);
console.log('style', svg1.style.width + 'x' + svg1.style.height);
console.log('client', svg1.clientWidth + 'x' + svg1.clientHeight);
console.log('offset', svg1.offsetWidth + 'x' + svg1.offsetHeight);
```

**CSS**

```
#svg1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Great question. ```clientWidth``` and ```clientHeight``` did the job for me.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Use the [`getBBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) function:

> The `SVGGraphicsElement.getBBox()` method allows us to determine the coordinates of the smallest rectangle in which the object fits. [...]

http://jsfiddle.net/Xkv3X/1/

```
var bBox = svg1.getBBox();
console.log('XxY', bBox.x + 'x' + bBox.y);
console.log('size', bBox.width + 'x' + bBox.height);
```

Comment: Is there no way to treat it like an HTML element and get the actual size the `svg` element is occupying despite what has been drawn? http://jsfiddle.net/Xkv3X/4/

Comment: Btw, I'm trying to determine the size of the canvas that I can draw on before rendering shapes.

Comment: I think it might be better to check available size of container (the div which contains your svg) then you can set appropriate size to you svg

Comment: That seems to be the only cross-browser way to do it... `getBoundingClientRect` gives me 400x400 in Chrome28, but FireFox23 reports 281x81.

Comment: @Langdon that's just been fixed in Firefox. Firefox 33 will report something similar to Chrome.

Comment: Today I reported a problem with getBoundingClientRect for FireFox 38 when symbol/use are used. In this case getBoundingClientRect extends the element to the border of viewBox. Also there is a known issue about stroke-width. So getBoundingClientRect is not cross browser solution for now.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=getboundingclientrect - all looks okay now, FF12+, Chrome 4+. I suspect those FF bugs get fixed in the same major version numbers as minor updates.

Comment: This doesn't take into account scale. My SVG element with CSS `transform: scale(5, 5)`, and which renders as 17000x3000 returns getBBox() of only 600x100.

Answer (score 72):

FireFox have problemes for getBBox(), i need to do this in vanillaJS.

I've a better Way and is the same result as real svg.getBBox() function !

With this good post : [Get the real size of a SVG/G element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847684/get-the-real-size-of-a-svg-g-element?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
var el   = document.getElementById("yourElement"); // or other selector like querySelector()
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(); // get the bounding rectangle

console.log( rect.width );
console.log( rect.height);
```

Comment: this one ! as said firefox has problems yet this works in most browsers :)

Comment: returns zero when the svg is hidden(for example in bootstrap tab)

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=getboundingclientrect - all looks okay now, FF12+, Chrome 4+

Comment: documentation: [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 9):

I'm using Firefox, and my working solution is very close to obysky. The only difference is that the method you call in an svg element will return multiple rects and you need to select the first one.

```
var chart = document.getElementsByClassName("chart")[0];
var width = chart.getClientRects()[0].width;
var height = chart.getClientRects()[0].height;
```

Comment: This is the way to get the size before CSS `transform` is applied.

Answer (score 8):

SVG has properties `width` and `height`. They return an object `SVGAnimatedLength` with two properties: `animVal` and `baseVal`. This interface is used for animation, where `baseVal` is the value *before* animation. From what I can see, this method returns consistent values in both Chrome and Firefox, so I think it can also be used to get calculated size of SVG.

Comment: where svg is your element...
    let svgWidth = svg.width.baseVal.value ;
    let svgHeight = svg.height.baseVal.value ;

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on Firefox at the moment - it'll give you an initial value but if you change the svg dimensions and try it again it gives you the original value.

Answer (score 4):

This is the consistent cross-browser way I found:

```
var heightComponents = ['height', 'paddingTop', 'paddingBottom', 'borderTopWidth', 'borderBottomWidth'],
    widthComponents = ['width', 'paddingLeft', 'paddingRight', 'borderLeftWidth', 'borderRightWidth'];

var svgCalculateSize = function (el) {

    var gCS = window.getComputedStyle(el), // using gCS because IE8- has no support for svg anyway
        bounds = {
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        };

    heightComponents.forEach(function (css) { 
        bounds.height += parseFloat(gCS[css]);
    });
    widthComponents.forEach(function (css) {
        bounds.width += parseFloat(gCS[css]);
    });
    return bounds;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

From Firefox 33 onwards you can call getBoundingClientRect() and it will work normally, i.e. in the question above it will return 300 x 100.

Answer (score 2):

Use .getAttribute()!

```js
var height = document.getElementById('rect').getAttribute("height");
var width = document.getElementById('rect').getAttribute("width");
var x = document.getElementById('rect').getAttribute("x");
alert("height: " + height + ", width: " + width + ", x: " + x);
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <rect width="300" height="100" x="50" y="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" id="rect"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

A save method to determine the width and height unit of **any** element (no padding, no margin) is the following:

```
let div   = document.querySelector("div");
let style = getComputedStyle(div);

let width  = parseFloat(style.width.replace("px", ""));
let height = parseFloat(style.height.replace("px", ""));
```