# What is the type of the <svg> element in typescript

Tags: html, typescript, casting

I am implementing the following class:

```
export class BbSVGElement extends HTMLElement implements HTMLCanvasElement { ... }
```

The problem is that I can't find the type of the `<svg>` element in typescript: `<span>` elements are `HTMLSpanElement`, `<canvas>` elements are `HTMLCanvasElement`, etc.

I ask because to implement a simple task such as the `height()` function, I need to get the bounding box of the element. According to [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18148142/9329985), this is the right way to do it:

```
height(): number { return this.getBBox().height}
```

But since `this` refers to an `HTMLElement`, of course `Property 'getBBox' does not exist on type 'BbSVGElement'.ts(2339)`

So I tried with castings of all kinds; things like:

```
return (<SVGElement> this).getBBox().width
return (<SVGSVGElement> this).getBBox().width
```

of course I could do something like

```
return (<any> this).getBBox().width
```

or

```
return this.offsetWidth // <-- This property here comes from HTMLElement
```

But I'd rather not if possible.

So: **What would be the right casting to do? Or would there be another option I missed?**

Comment: The SVG-DOM interface types for SVG are documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model#SVG_interfaces

Comment: SVGElement isn't going to be under HTML... it's independent.  I don't use Typescript, but I'm guessing you'll have to import something else.

Comment: Are you looking for `SVGGraphicsElement`?  That's the type of thing with a [`getBBox()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox), right?

Comment: What is `BbSVGElement` meant to represent? You shouldn't be doing `extends HTMLElement implements HTMLCanvasElement` because you're not reimplementing `<canvas>` (and `<canvas>` and SVG are completely separate things anyway)  - and you shouldn't extend `HTMLElement` unless you're defining HTML5 Web Components. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: After thinking about it more - can you confirm that the `<svg>` element you're referring to **is an `<svg>` element inside HTML** - rather than an SVG element within an SVG document?

Comment: @Dai I can confirm that the <svg> element I am referring to is an <svg> element inside HTML.

Comment: @Dai I am trying to implement dual painting mode: provide the option to paint as SVG or as canvas. I therefore must implement every function in HTMLCanvasElement. extending HTMLElement does most of the job.

Comment: @Brad Yes, SVGElement is under html, no import required.

Comment: @jcalz No, I'm not looking for SVGGraphicsElement. as @Dai pointed out in his answer, I was looking for `type SVGOrHtmlElement = HTMLElement & SVGElement;`

Comment: @MarcheRemi The name `SVGOrHtmlElement ` is incorrect because it's an intersection type, not a union-type. The correct name for your case would be `SVGAndHtmlElement` (or the `SvgInHtml` name I used in my posted answer).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> What is the type of the `<svg>` element in TypeScript?

The interface type of `<svg>` elements in an `*.svg` document (i.e. the SVG DOM) is `SVGElement`. The type of an `<svg>` element within a HTML document (i.e. the HTML DOM) is actually a prototype-less object **that implements both** `HTMLElement` **and** `SVGElement`!

So in TypeScript, you can represent an `<svg>` element in the DOM by using an *intersection type* (which represents a type that combines *all members* of two or more types, compared to a *union type* which represents a type that combines *shared members* of two or more types).

Like so:

```
type SvgInHtml = HTMLElement & SVGElement;

const svgElement: SvgInHtml = document.createElement('svg') as SvgInHtml;

const svgHeight = svgElement.getBBox().height; // Using `SVGElement.getBBox()`.
const htmlWidth = svgElement.offsetWidth;      // Using `HTMLElement.offsetWidth`
```

I see you want to represent this using a *derived* class - but that is incorrect (as class inheritance only allows a single parent class), instead either use a non-encapsulated `type SvgInHtml` reference, or encapsulate it in an object or new class (with no superclass):

```
type SvgInHtml = HTMLElement & SVGElement;

class MySvgWrapper {

    constructor( private readonly svgElement: SvgInHtml ) {
    }

    get height(): number {
        return this.svgElement.getBBox().height;
    }
}
```

---

(This is my original answer I posted before I understood your problem correctly - I'm keeping it here and accessible because I feel it may still be useful for other people who find this question but have a different problem to yours):

The base SVG-DOM interface for all (most?) SVG elements is `SVGElement` [which is documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement).

Assuming you're using TypeScript 3.x or later which has the SVG-DOM interfaces in `lib.dom.d.ts` (see the content of my answer below the line) then you need to change your `class` declaration to this:

```
export class MySVGElement extends SVGElement {
    
}
```

Since TypeScript 3.x, TypeScript's "standard library" of typings for the HTML DOM includes the SVG DOM interfaces in `lib/lib.dom.d.ts`, so you shouldn't need to download, import, or add anything - just use `SVGElement` (and its derived interfaces) directly.

[If you open the current TypeScript `lib.dom.d.ts` in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts) you can search for `"SVGElement"` (and any other SVG-DOM interface, like `SVGGraphicsElement`) and see it's declared in there:

e.g.:

```
/** SVG elements whose primary purpose is to directly render graphics into a group. */
interface SVGGraphicsElement extends SVGElement, SVGTests {
    readonly transform: SVGAnimatedTransformList;
    getBBox(options?: SVGBoundingBoxOptions): DOMRect;
    getCTM(): DOMMatrix | null;
    getScreenCTM(): DOMMatrix | null;
    addEventListener<K extends keyof SVGElementEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: SVGGraphicsElement, ev: SVGElementEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    removeEventListener<K extends keyof SVGElementEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: SVGGraphicsElement, ev: SVGElementEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
    removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
}
```

If you get any errors relating to unknown/undefined types then please post that as a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Although what worked for me was `HTMLElement & SVGSVGElement`! Like this: `const [ref, { width }] = useMeasure<HTMLElement & SVGSVGElement>();`

Comment: maybe use `HTMLOrSVGElement` predefined interface

Comment: Why not simply, `SVGSVGElement`? It's exactly what the OP asked for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement

Comment: @tvanc `SVGSVGElement` is not a `HTMLElement`: the `SVGSVGElement` type is only appropriate for use on the "inner" representation of an "outer" `<svg>` element in HTML. For example, `SVGSVGElement` lacks members defined on `HTMLElement` which _do_ apply to "outer" `<svg>` elements in HTML, such as `hidden`, `title`, and so on.