# TypeScript type of an SVG icon when impoerted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What is the proper type when using an imported icon (e.g. SVG) in TypeScript

`import icon_name from './icon_file.svg'`

```
function icon(): MISSING_TYPE
{
  return icon_name;
}
```

I am particularly interested in React but I don't feel `React.ReactNode` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In your function this is only one return possibility? In typescript is [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html), so compiler specify returned type by itself.

Btw solution is here:
[What is the type of the <svg> element in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63165896/what-is-the-type-of-the-svg-element-in-typescript)

Comment: They appear to be ```string```s however...