# How to pass an image as prop in react/typescript to another component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to typescript and don't know how to pass an image (svg) in a different component as a prop in typescript

**this is my code:**

Image Import

```
import internet from "./assets/internet.svg"
```

passing it products array along with the image into Products component

```
function App() {

  const products = [
    {
      id: 1,
      img: { internet },
      heading: "Access a private marketplace",
      desc:
        "Product Description.",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <main>
      <Products products={products} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Products.tsx:

```

```
type Product = {
  id: number;
  img: any; // unsure about type, "string" didn't work so i chose "any"
  heading: string;
  desc: string;
};

type ProductsProps = {
  products: Product[];
};

const Products = ({ products }: ProductsProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((product, id) => (
        <div>
          id: {product.id}
          img: <img src={product.img} alt={product.img} />
          heading: {product.heading}
          desc: {product.desc}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

when i run this the alt tag returns **[object Object]**

```

Comment: I guess "img: { internet }," should be "img: internet,". To many curly brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggestion 1**: `img: { internet }` means `img: { internet: internet }`.
your type is expecting `img: internet`

**Suggestion 2**: Assuming you are expecting only SVGs are your images, SVGs are also elements so you can use them directly without an IMG tag like below.

```js
<div>
  id: {product.id}
  img: {product.img}
  heading: {product.heading}
  desc: {product.desc}
</div>
```

In case you want to type the SVG image property you can reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/63165963/14362614

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you also weren't able to display your image properly. The problem lies in the way you declared your **products** array in *App.tsx*.

On line 6, `img`'s type is an object with the sole key: `internet` such as:

```js
const projectImg = {
  internet: "link.to.your.image.svg"
}
```

This prevents your `Products` component from rendering the image properly, since the `<img/>` tag expects `product.img` to be a string.

Replace your products definition with the following code and it should run just fine.

```js
import internet from "./assets/internet.svg";

const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: internet, // notice the lack of curly braces
    heading: "Access a private marketplace",
    desc: "Product Description.",
  },
];
```