# Why the function element.style.height in JavaScript may not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, element

I cannot get the object's height in js code. My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
      <object onload="loadMarkers()" type="image/svg+xml" data="WorldMap.svg" id="worldMap"></object>
      <script src="project.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS code (the name of the file in HTML is right, I checked it):

```
function loadMarkers() {
    var h = document.getElementById("worldMap").style.height;
    console.log(h);
}
```

The console output is an empty line. If I write

```
var h = Number(document.getElementById("worldMap").style.height);
console.log(h);
```

the output is 0.

Comment: try to write to console document.getElementById("worldMap") and view object

Comment: Do you have CSS code that actually sets the height of the object? If not, that's why there is no output. If you're trying to get the actual height, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18147915/262708).

Comment: @LilDevil yes, I have a CSS code "width: 100%; height: auto"; I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @VlaMai; it gets the right object

Comment: @GabrielaTicu this object has parameter style with parater height ?

Comment: @VlaMai yes, in the external stylesheet

Comment: @GabrielaTicu no in console output

Comment: @Gabriela Ticu based on the CSS you posted, if your code above worked, I would only expect it to return "auto". Follow the link I posted above and check the highly voted answers.

Comment: my theory at start it's actual 0 height y need to wait when it onload="loadMarkers()" and get heaight after

Comment: @VlaMai right in the console no, but when I hover the console output, it highlights the object and under the object, I see its width and height

Comment: write in css height: 100 px and try

Comment: @VlaMai no changes :(

Comment: setTimeout(function () {
  var h = Number(document.getElementById("worldMap").style.height);
console.log(h);
}, 5000)

Comment: @VlaMai output: 0

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I used document.getElementById("worldMap").getBoundingClientRect().height and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.offsetHeight` instead of `.style.height`:

```js
var h = Number(document.getElementById("worldMap").offsetWidth);
console.log(h);
```